# Displaying a Variable using Java

Tags: java, string, variables, char

So basically I want to display a polynomial `x^2-x-2.0 (x* x-x-2.0)`
but I want to declare it as a variable before hand 
ex: `polynomial = x*x-x-2.0` (this obviously doesn't work).

I've tried defining the polynomial as a string, ,and the x as a string, I've tried defining it as a char but nothing works!! Is it even possible to display it so that

```
System.out.println ("The polynomial is:    " + polynomial);
```

where the polynomial is equal to `x*x-x-2.0`.

I want it to display the x's as x's and not as numbers. Please help!

Comment: String polynomial = "(x*x-x-2.0)";
System.out.println ("The polynomial is: " + polynomial);

Comment: it doesn't recognize x! I get an error

Comment: I fixed it, my mistake was that I forgot to delete the other area where I had defined polynomial!! It works now though thank you

Answer (score 1):

@Jane Doe -

It sounds like you might want to:

1) Define a new Java class for "Polynomial".

2) Your class would have different "members" for each order in the polynomial.

3) It would also [override toString()](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) to print the way you want to.

4) It will probably also have different operations to "do something useful", like "add()" and "multiply()".

Here's an example:

http://vh216602.truman.edu/agarvey/cs171/poly.java

Comment: is there a simpler way that doesn't involve defining a new class? I need to make the code as basic as possible

Comment: @Jane Doe - "classes" *ARE* the "basic unit of code" in Java.  Every line of code you write in Java, you write inside of a Java class.  It doesn't get any simpler ;)  PS: What's happening next in [Blind Spot](http://blindspot.wikia.com/wiki/Jane_Doe)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different letter for the calculation and the print.

Comment: but what do I define the polynomial and x as? string or chars or what?

Comment: If you are just trying to display the variable use a string. Are you trying to do calculations with the polynomial?

Comment: no, I just want it so that when polynomial = x* x-x-2 I could just do System.out.println ("The polynomial is:    " + polynomial) instead of System.out.println ("The polynomial is:   x* x-x-2 ")

Comment: If the characters in your string are making it not act like a string you can try using escape characters( \ ) on the troublesome parts

Comment: for some reason whenever I do string polynomial= "(x* x-x-2) I get an error because it doesn't recognize x, so then i try and define x and that gives me more errors

Comment: That is really odd. I'm assuming u did have closing quotes tho right?

Comment: yes I did have closing quotes. this is the message I get: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
 polynomial= x*x*x-x-1.0;
              ^
  first type:  String
  second type: String

Comment: Okay I figured out my mistake! I wasn't consistent with my naming!! Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Maybe its the "^"? I'm not clear as to whether your using that or not - but if so try "\^" it might be one of those things that needs it
I can't claim knowledge of this though - this is completely unfamiliar territory for me at this point

Comment: Use "\\^". The carrot symbol is used in regular expressions, which may be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class dis {
 int x;
 String polynomial;
 dis()
 {
    x=5;
    String temp=Integer.toString(x);
    polynomial=temp+'*'+temp+'-'+temp+'-'+"2.0";
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     dis t=new dis();
     //System.out.println(t.toString());
     System.out.println(t.polynomial);
 }
}
```

Output:
5*5-5-2.0

Answer (score 0):

**Why is it even an issue?**
`x*x-x-2.0` is a numerical expression (double) and hence assigning it to a String object may give compile time error. Just enclose the expression within " " like: `"x*x - x - 2.0"` and the expression will be concatenated to the String polinomial.